# If $(A,+,\cdot)$ and $(B,+,\cdot)$ are rings and there exists a homomorphism such that $\phi:A\rightarrow B$ then $\phi(1_A)=1_B$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ring-homomorphism

The idea of my proof was that if we have a neutral element in a ring than it is unique.
I have showed that

$$\phi(a)=\phi(a)\cdot \phi(1_A)=\phi(1_A)\cdot \phi(a).$$

For all elements that are in the imageset of $\phi$, $\phi(1_A)$ acts as a neutral element, how can I argue that because of that $\phi(1_A)$ must be a neutral element of all elements in $B$?

Comment: For rings with identity one demands that they send $1$ to $1$. You cannot show that here since you do not necessarily have many units.

Answer (score 2):

No, you cannot argue like that. Just consider$$\begin{array}{rccc}\phi\colon&\mathbb R&\longrightarrow&\mathbb R^{2\times2}\\&x&\mapsto&\begin{bmatrix}x&0\\0&0\end{bmatrix},\end{array}$$which is a ring homomorphism. However,$$\phi(1)=\begin{bmatrix}1&0\\0&0\end{bmatrix}\neq\begin{bmatrix}1&0\\0&1\end{bmatrix}=\operatorname{Id}.$$Note, however, that it is usually part of the definition of ring homomorphism that, when we are dealing with rings with unity, $\phi$ must be such that $\phi(1_Q)=1_B$.

Comment: Could it work if we also knew that $\phi$ is surjective?

Comment: @New2Math Yes; then your argument works, as every element of $B$ can be expressed as $\phi(a)$ for some $a \in A$.

Comment: There is still some confusion. The Argumentation would go like that in Theory: Let $b\in B$ then there exist a $a\in A$ such that $b=\phi(a)$ then $b\phi(1)=\phi(a\cdot 1)= b = \phi(1 \cdot a) =\phi(1)b$. What confuses me is that $b$ can have several preimages, how do we deal with this in the Argumentation?

Comment: We don't. The fact that $b$ has **one** preimage is enough for that proof.

Comment: sorry for the possibly dumb question but why is that enough? Or to rephrase it why is it sufficíent to only consider one preimage of b?

Comment: Actually, what you should have proved was that, if $b$ has some preimage $a$, then $\phi(1)b=b$. But, after that is is done, then you shall have proved that $\phi(1)$ is the unity of $B$. The proof is still valid if you replace a preimage of $b$ by another one.

Comment: I still don't understand we are deriving the truth of a Statement from the truth of other Statements: $\phi \text{surj.}\Rightarrow\exists a\in A:\phi(a)=b\Rightarrow \exists a\in A: \phi(1)\phi(a)=\phi(1)b\Rightarrow b= \phi(1)b$, if all links to the chains are proved then the end of the chain must be true if the begin of the chain is true. What would happen if we found a proof that the end of the chain is false, seperate from the chainproof?

Comment: That is a very abstract question. Perhaps that you might consider the possibility of posting it it as a new question.

Answer (score 0):

Well, this is not the case. Take the zero mapping $\phi:a\mapsto 0_B$ which is a homomorphism.

In general, if $\phi:G\rightarrow H$ is a homomorphism between groups, then $\phi(1_G)=1_H$.

But if $\phi:M\rightarrow N$ is a homomorphism between monoids (similarly to in your case of rings), then not necessarily $\phi(1_M)=1_N$.

Answer (score 0):

This won't work; we take for instance $\phi:\mathbb{Z}\to \mathbb{Z}$ by $\phi(x)=0$ for all $x$. $\phi(x+y)=\phi(x)+\phi(y)$ and $\phi(xy)=\phi(x)\phi(y)$.

The issue is that here $\phi(1)=0$, and indeed $\phi(1)\phi(x)=\phi(x)$, but this is just because $\phi(x)=0$ for all $x\in \mathbb{Z}$.

Answer (score 0):

There is no argument for that.

(Observe e.g. that the function that sends every element of $A$ to $0_B$).

That is why it is actually a part of the *definition* of (unital) ringhomomorphism concerning rings with identity.

---

Sidenote:

The fact that in the definition of grouphomomorphism it is not demanded that they send identity to identity must be looked at as *exceptional*.

It is a consequence of the fact that based on $\phi(ab)=\phi(a)\phi(b)$ it can be shown that $\phi$ respects idempotent elements (i.e. if $a^2=a$ then $\phi(a)^2=\phi(a^2)=\phi(a)$). Further there is only one idempotent element in a group which is the identity. This guarantees the $\phi$ will send identity to identity. But again: this is exceptional.